# Does Spring Data JPA projection optimize the sql?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Spring boot: 1.5.10
spring Data JPA : 1.11.10

IE MyEntity

```
 class MyEntity{
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private Integer age;
    // getter setter
 }
```

My MyProjection

```
 interface MyProjection{ String getName() }
```

MyEntityRepository

```
 ...
  MyProjection findById(Long Id)
  ...
```

when I call the findById function, the generate sql is:

```
 select myentity0_.id, myentity0_.name,myentity0_.age from MyEntity myentity0_ where ...
```

Why it also select the age column ?

Comment: This seems odd, I just did a quick test in two different project, an older Spring-Data 1.5.1 + Hibernate and a newer Spring-Data 1.11.9 + EclipseLink, in both cases only the column from the projection interface was selected.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek I use javax.persistence.* instead of EclipseLink. Do you use spring data JPA?

Comment: JPA is a specification, there are many implementation, the default JPA provider for Spring Boot is Hibernate (which is typically swap out for EclipseLink).  My tests used two different JPA providers, two different versions of Spring Boot/Data, and in both cases only the column in the projection was selected. If you can reproduce it in a standalone project on GitHub, I could look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring Data JPA should only select the specific columns it needs when dealing with interface projections.

I have just tested it in a simple project based on your question and have observed the following query being executed:

```
select myentity0_.name as col_0_0_ from my_entity myentity0_ where myentity0_.id=?
```

This would suggest that you application is behaving differently. Have a look at the sample project and compare it to your own to see if you can spot any differences: https://github.com/roberthunt/spring-data-interface-projection